# Change the value of a list's element

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have created a list holding various values. However i wanted to know how i could update/replace a piece of data in a list of a specific position. For example if i had a list as follows: `[hello, goodbye, welcome, message]` and i wanted to replace the string in position `2` with the following string: `'wave'`. how would i do that?? i tried the code below, but it shifts the values to the right and inserts a new piece of data where the position is given:

```
MyList = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'welcome', 'message']
MyList.insert(2, 'wave')
```

Comment: Have you tried assigning it? `MyList[2] = ...`

Comment: How would i use MyList[2]??

Comment: i tried MyList[2].append(data) or MyList[2].insert(data). It didn't work

Comment: @HamzahAkhtar wnnmaw's answer is complete, but for sake of brevity: `MyList[2] = 'wave'`. Both `MyList[2].append` and `MyList[2].insert` would do work if `MyList[2]` was a `list` (e.g. `MyList = ['hello','goodbye',['this','is','a','list'],'last element']`), but it's a string instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists are **mutable**, which means you can alter them in place.  Therefore you can simple assign a new value to index 2:

```
>>> lst = range(10)
>>> lst
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> lst[2] = "new value"
>>> lst
[0, 1, 'new value', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

`dicts` are also mutable:

```
>>> d = {1:'a',2:'b'}
>>> d[2] = "new value"
>>> d
{1: 'a', 2: 'new value'}
```

However, strings and tuples **ARE NOT**.  You can iterate through them which sometimes causes confusion, (especially the sub-string notation vs. slicing)

```
>>> aString = "Hello, my name is Dave"
'my '
>>> aString[7:9]
'my'
>>> aString[7:9] = "MY"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Similarly,

```
>>> tup = (1,2,3)
>>> tup[0]
1
>>> tup[0] = 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

For strings, you can "cheat" by converting them into a list (`split()`), mutating them, then putting them back into a string (`join()`), but this is *not* actual mutation of the string in place

Comment: To go with your mutability statement, you may want to contrast tuples with lists to help OP with deeper understanding of both.

Comment: @AdamSmith, yes, good idea, I'll work up a couple of examples

Comment: @HamzahAkhtar, Great! Since this worked for you, please mark this as the "accepted answer" so that other users can quickly find the answer should they have the same question

Comment: What if the position is assigned to a variable. Say for example the position 2 is replaced with a variable index. Could you still use lst[index] = 'New Value'??

Comment: By the way, i have to wait a couple of minutes before i can accept an answer (The site wont allow me to accept it)

Comment: Yes, good question, anywhere a value exists in Python, you can replace it with a variable name (so long as the types line up).  You could even   put a function call in there if that function returned an ```int```.  Oh yes, I forgot about the time limit